# How to make an object/uv sphere rotate and change colors without changing camera position

Tags: objects

I have to make a magic ball like this.
http://luisbc.deviantart.com/art/Magic-Ball-II-364636015
I want to do so by kepping the ball fixed and only the lights/colors move in a similar manner to above link.

Comment: Hello and welcome. In which renderer do you need this effect? Internal or Cycles?

Comment: I don't know exactly the diff b/w these two renders.Though i made one ball moving with bezier modifier and just rendered it by adding lights.But it didn't work like the ball has to fixed .If you could help it will be great of you.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61457/making-glass-orbs-with-effects-inside/72038#72038 You can animate plane behind orb.

Comment: I've modified answer there (Final thoughts section) for your needs.

Comment: It's great .Thank you.Would you please help me like i am noob to blender just started using it and didn't know that glass shader thing also exists.I will be great it you could tell me some resource or like guide to start things.

Comment: There are lots of nice resources for free mainly. Try YouTube, blender nation or paid one like cgcookie. Or search here for resource topic. I think it exist as I recall.